# draw a simple board for tic tac toe in python, gives error of IndentationError

Tags: python

```
def display_board(board):
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[7] + ' | ' + board[8] + ' | ' + board[9])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[4] + ' | ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[6])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[1] + ' | ' + board[2] + ' | ' + board[3])
    print('   |   |')
```

Comment: There's not enough to go on here, but the problem is generally caused by inconsistent use of tabs and spaces.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Python style guidelines suggest using 4 spaces instead of tab characters - your issue is almost certainly because in your file, you have mixed tabs and spaces or indented improperly. I suggest either using an editor that converts tabs to spaces or using spaces yourself.

As your code stands here, it is perfectly valid Python, so it's impossible for anyone here to tell you exactly what your problem is.

Comment: If a proper answer is impossible, why answer?